# Running speeds for young males & females at different ages

Tags: data-request, sports

I'm looking for an open dataset that has **aggregate running speeds** over short distances, that divides the data into **Male/Female** and **Age Groups**. The data should be from regular human beings, like students or ameteur athletes, and not from Olympic level competition.

The exact raw data isn't so important, but my goal is to generate median max speed per age and gender. Any data that is related to soccer/football or other sports is also welcome.

The data can be any format or level of machine readability, and I'll use the data as a reference, so I don't have any strict license requirements.

Perfect dataset would look like this

```
M,13,median_top_speed,20
M,15,median_top_speed,22
M,17,median_top_speed,24
M,19,median_top_speed,26
M,21,median_top_speed,27
F,13,median_top_speed,19
F,15,median_top_speed,21
F,17,median_top_speed,23
F,19,median_top_speed,25
F,21,median_top_speed,26
```

Comment: Well, Soviet/Russian "ГТО" norms: http://www.gto.ru/norms

Comment: @StanislavKralin that would make a good answer!

Comment: BTW, what is "young" and what is "short"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this 2015 paper which has data for 11-18 year old Norwegian male and female running 60 meters:

> [Performance Development in Adolescent Track and Field Athletes According to Age, Sex and Sport Discipline](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4456243/)

[image]

The link to download the data was dead (and I notified the author), but an archive is available on the wayback machine.

https://web.archive.org/web/20150501075113/http://www.friidrett.no/stevner/statistikk1/alle%20tiders/Sider/Norgesbestegjennomalletider.aspx